# Neural Network --- Back propagation algorithm error (In javascript!)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, neural-network

I have read quite a few back prop algorithms and i have no idea why mine is doing what it is doing.

### Some notes before reading

- No-hidden layer can "learn" all linear equations given a training set.  Using 5 / 2 training it will even learn as accurate as 0.01% average error (fairly low)
- When a hidden layer is used.  The network will only output 2 values.  One if both inputs are positive one if both inputs are negative.
- The activation function of inputs -> hiddens -> (up to) outputs is f(x) = 1 / (1 + e^-x)
- The activation function of outputs is linear (f(x) = x)
- Error calculations

  - I believe this is where my possible error is at!
  - Outputs:  `E(k) = (target(k) - O(k).output) * f'(O(k).output) = (target - actual) * 1` linear activation fn gets 1 as derivative
  - Inputs and hiddens: `E(j) = sum(w(kj) * E(k)) * f'(N(j).output) = sum(w(kj) * E(k) * N(j).output * (1 - N(j).output)`
- The full source code can be found here
  http://www.github.com/primeagen/neural-js

---

### The Source!  Its in javascript!

- Remember: Feedforward and output error seems to be correct since a non hidden layer network can learn any linear function and extrapolate well beyond its training set with a 0.01%.  So i believe that is correct

### Back prop error calculation

```
// Output layer
for (var i = 0; i < this._outputs.length; i++) {
    var o = this._outputs[i];
    o.error = targetOutputs[i] - o.output;
    this._mse += o.error * o.error;
}

// Go through hidden layers
for (var cIdx = this._layers.length - 2; cIdx > 0; cIdx--) {
    var curr = this._layers[cIdx];
    var next = this._layers[cIdx + 1];

    // Go through hidden neurons
    for (var hN = 0, hLen = curr.length; hN < hLen; hN++) {
        var h = curr[hN];
        var sum = 0;

        for (var nN = 0, nLen = next.length; nN < nLen; nN++) {
            var n = next[nN];
            sum += n.w[hN] * n.error;
        }
        h.error = sum * h.dActivationFn(h.output);
    }
}
```

### The activation function and its derivative

```
/**
 * The logisticFunction function is 1 / (1 + e ^ (-x))
 * @param x
 */
function logisticFunction(x) {
    return 1 / (1 + Math.pow(Math.E, -x));
}

/**
 * The derivative of the logistic function
 * @param {Number} x
 * @returns {Number}
 */
function dLogisticFunction(x) {
    return x * (1 - x);
}
```

`Neuron.dActivation = dLogisticFunction`

My network just converges onto an answer (its random) and no matter the input (when positive) the value will not change when trained with 100+ data points...

Any idea?

Comment: The derivative of the logistic function is `sigmoid(input) * (1d - sigmoid(input))` where `sigmoid` is `logisticFunction` in your code.

Comment: I believe that is what i am doing.  `h.output` = `h.activationFn(h.input)` which is the logistic function.  So `h.error = Sum(weights from h to n * n.error) * h.dActivationFn(h.output)`

Comment: You're right, wasn't going through all of your code. This was just catching my eye.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut one of the experiences i am having is that the outputs are almost always ==(ish) (0.00001) to 0 or 1 which makes it error almost always appear as 0